# Django - present current date and time in template

Tags: python, html, django, datetime, django-templates

How can one present current data and time in django's template?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try using built-in django template tags and filters:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#now

Examples:

```
It is {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
It is {% now "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" %}
```

Comment: There is an option to translate this built-in templates ?

Comment: @KyluAce modify the language in settings.py

Comment: To complement this answer: if you need the current date as a variable (`date` or `datetime` instead of just a `str`) you can find a few options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336898/9225671) I wrote some time ago.

Comment: can this display days like Sunday to Monday?

Answer (score 2):

The full list of datetime formats can be [found in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date). Using the format options there, you can construct the current datetime in whatever format you want. For example,

```html
It is {% now "l, F j, Y g:i A" %}.
```

displays

```
It is Wednesday, September 27, 2023 11:58 PM.
```

on the webpage, and

```html
It is {% now "" %}.

It is {% now "N j, Y" %}.
```

both display

```
It is Sept. 28, 2023.
```