# DJANGO Different Timezone Display

Tags: python, django

Django Beginner here. I'm trying to display different timezones in my template but it's not displaying.

HTML File

```
  {% load tz %}

  {% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
      Paris time: {{ value }}
  {% endtimezone %}

  {% timezone None %}
      Server time: {{ value }}
  {% endtimezone %}
```

OUTPUT

```
No Display in HTML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're not getting anything displayed because you haven't passed any context to your template. You would do something like this:

```
    from django.utils import timezone
    ...
    return render(request, template, context={'value': timezone.now()})
```

Another option is to use django's built-in `{% now &}` with whatever format you want.

Similar question:
[Django - present current date and time in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637768/django-present-current-date-and-time-in-template)

Now docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#now

Date filters to include with now:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date

Answer (score 2):

In setting.py change `TIME_ZONE`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
```

views.py should look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def index(request):
    france = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'now':now, 'france': france} )
```

And home.html should look like this:

```
France time: {{france}}
Server time: {{ now }}
```

It should work

Comment: Hello & Welcome to SO. Link only answers are discouraged. Could you rewrite this by expanding, and adding the link to the Github place that you point to? Thanks.